# AnyCPU .net wrapper for PCRE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, pcre, pcre.net

I want an AnyCPU dll for PCRE for C#. In the currently available PCRE.NET we can make it either 32 bit or 64 due to its C++ dependencies. Is there an implementation that can be truly MSIL, like using DllImport with an if else for selecting the correct source based on the application. If not, Can anyone guide as to how to make one. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [PCRE.NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net).

PCRE.NET is an AnyCPU assembly, which ships both an x86 *and* an x64 version of the native library inside. It will choose the correct one at runtime. It won't run or ARM or any other architecture though.

If you want some details, the main MSIL assembly contains two mixed-mode assemblies in its resources. At runtime, it will choose the correct one, unpack it into `%TEMP%`, then load and use it.

You need to have the [MSVC 2015 redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003) package installed though, because the C++/CLI part depends on it.

---

To make the library compatible with .NET 4, you'll have to replace some interfaces like `IReadOnlyList<T>` with `IList<T>`, `Volatile.Write` with `Thread.VolatileWrite` etc.

As for this line:

```cpp
System::Threading::Volatile::Write(_calloutInfoByPatternPosition, dict);
```

You could replace it with:

```cpp
#undef MemoryBarrier
System::Threading::Thread::MemoryBarrier();
_calloutInfoByPatternPosition = dict;
```

Not that pretty, but works.

Last but not least, make sure to run the **build script** (`build/Build.Bat`) to compile the library, as it will execute the steps required to embed the mixed-mode assemblies inside PCRE.NET.dll.

Comment: Ok, This might be a stupid question, But While adding the reference, does anything else needs to be added to the references of the project in use, or just refering PCRE.NET.dll enough? As I can see The PCRE.NET.dll is AnyCPU but the PCRE.NET.Wrapper is 64 bit...

Comment: Nope, PCRE.NET.dll is enough, it embeds both PCRE.NET.Wrapper.x86.dll and PCRE.NET.Wrapper.x64.dll if you use the released precompiled version (or use the build script). The best way to use the library is through the NuGet package though.

Comment: I'll have to download the source and build the sln as my application is on .net 4.0 while the one from NuGet is build using .net 4.5

Comment: Ok I see, then just make sure you use the build script after you change the code -  it will package the self-contained dll. You'll have to switch a couple interfaces like IReadOnlyList to IList on the way.

Comment: `Error C3083 'Volatile': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type PCRE.NET.Wrapper\InternalRegex.cpp 207
Error C2039 'Write': is not a member of 'System::Threading' PCRE.NET.Wrapper\InternalRegex.cpp 207
Error C3861 'Write': identifier not found PCRE.NET.Wrapper\InternalRegex.cpp 207
Error (active)  name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name PCRE.NET.Wrapper\InternalRegex.cpp 207
`
I am getting the below errors, can you shed any light on how to solve them

Comment: Yes, these are not available in .Net 4 -  use Thread.VolatileWrite instead of Volatile.Write.

Comment: Sorry again but I was able to solve all but 1 errors `no instance of overloaded function "System::Threading::Thread::VolatileWrite" matches the argument list PCRE.NET.Wrapper\InternalRegex.cpp 221`the arguments for VolatileWrite werean Ilist in one case and a dictionary in another.

Comment: @AnishaJain I expanded my answer

Comment: One final thing, when actually using the assembly, I get: `Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'PCRE.NET.Wrapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)`

Comment: Looks like you changed something in the `.vcxproj` file, which prevents the assembly from getting signed. Can't help much more there, look at the diff and make sure the `<LinkKeyFile>` tags are there.